# Read data attribute from select using native javascript

Tags: javascript

Problem is simple, I found some answers using jquery but none in native JS.

Not able to read the value of label, it should work in IE8+

```
var select = document.getElementById('test');

select.onchange = function() {
    //Value works fine 
    //alert(select.options[0].value);

    //How can I read data attribute?
    alert(select.options[0].data-label);
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="test">
    <option data-label="label-1" value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
    <option data-label="label-2" value="CH">China</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lnybn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is no native getData, you need to just say

```
getAttribute("data-label");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute

The newer version of this (check browser support! IE 11!)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

```
element.dataset.label
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getAttribute`.

Like this:

```
alert(select.options[0].getAttribute('data-label'));
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/Lnybn/1/

Comment: @RuntimeException, actually I didn't know of this. I had to search for answering this, which is why I answered it second